# Calling action page from form

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have used an html `<form>` tag in my ColdFusion code. The form `action` is set to an action page. The action page should be hit when submit button is clicked. But the action page code is not run.

I used logs to check if the page was even hit, but it turns out that the page is not accessed at all. All I get is a 500 error saying "there is some problem with the resource you are looking for".

The code for form is

```
<form action="vend_deliverables_edit_all_action.cfm" method="post" 
       onSubmit="return at_submit(this);">

     <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="#project_id#">
     <input type="submit" name="action" value="update">
```

The function `at_submit()` gets fired, but the action page does not. While clicking on Update button the error received is:

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Maybe if you show us some code.

Comment: the fact that you're seeing a 500, not a 404 suggests that *a* page is being processed. check the names of your form fields in case there are fields named foo and foo_date as Coldfusion treats the foo_date field as validation information and will generate errors. posting the form code would help a lot

Comment: Also, if you have a lot of form fields, it can cause an error at the JRun/Tomcat level which wouldn't be caught by ColdFusion.  I believe CF defaults to 200 form fields, might be 100, in any case if you have more than that you might need to increase the limit.

Comment: *Can anybody help?* Not without seeing some code, no ;-) Also, please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21606363/edit) to include the *full* error message and stack trace (if available). (BTW, if you are new to this site, here are some tips for [posting questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Comment: If you actually submit the form yourself, what is in the address bar of your browswer?  Is it the form page or the action page?

Comment: Usually CF provides with a detailed error description on browser, but here I am not getting one.

Comment: Can someone please tell me if there are some server side logs that can  be used to debug. This is a production server and hence CF debugging can not be used.

Comment: @DanBracuk : The address is of the action page when the error is shown.

Comment: Like the other commenters above, the 500 error is an error processing the ColdFusion page. When ColdFusion errors itself, it cannot even display the error messages you are used to. You have to look in the log files. It will give you more information, and will help diagnose the issue. These issues are strange for sure, but when I got these, it usually was because of too many fields, but that is only one of many possible issues. Get us the logs.

Comment: Where are the logs placed? c:/coldfusion9/logs has a number of files. which ones to look into?

Comment: It is actually in the JRUN log, since JRUN errors before passing the request to ColdFusion. Look in jrun_home/logs/{instance}-event.log. You will see something like this (if its the Post limit issue)        coldfusion.filter.FormScope$PostParametersLimitExceededException: POST parameters exceeds the maximum limit specified in the server.               Its not in the cF logs if it doesn't make it to CF. Thats what makes this type of error (500) tricky.

Comment: Thank you so much people... Checking the JRun logs did the trick. The "postparameterslimit" was set less than the number of fields being sent, and that caused the whole issue. I increased it and it worked.